# Select rows in a table that contain one name in a string vector

Tags: string, matlab, subset

I'm trying to subset a matlab table based on values in one column.  I'd like to select multiple rows, which contain any of the names in this string array: names = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Wilson"].  There is an example below for selecting a singular component, but I'd like to know how to select from an array...

Example selecting based on one descriptor:

```
load patients
patients = table(LastName,Age,Gender,Height,Weight,Smoker);
subset_patients = patients(strcmp(patients.LastName, 'Wilson'),:)
```

I'd like to do something like the code below - where I am selecting all the rows that include the names.  So I would get three rows of data, one for each name.

```
names = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Wilson"]
subset_patients_names = patients(strcmp(patients.LastName, names),:)
```

However this code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) instead of `strcmp`:

```
>> subset_patients_names = patients(ismember(patients.LastName, names),:)
subset_patients_names =
  3×6 table
    LastName     Age    Gender    Height    Weight    Smoker
    _________    ___    ______    ______    ______    ______
    'Smith'      38     'Male'    71        176       true  
    'Johnson'    43     'Male'    69        163       false 
    'Wilson'     40     'Male'    68        180       false
```

Note that the first column in the table `patients` contains *character vectors*, whereas `names` is an array of *strings*. The code above works because, as stated in the documenation of `ismember`,

> `ismember(A,B)`: `A` must belong to the same class as `B` with the following exceptions: [...]
>
> Cell arrays of character vectors can combine with character arrays or string arrays.